What's the difference between error.errorMessage and error.muleMessage?
I am trying to understand the mule error object and I am a bit confused with what I see in the debugger.
Say there is a http request call failure in my app and in the debugger I can see the error object with muleMessage property.
And if I right click on error object > copy value then I don't see muleMessage in there. There it's called errorMessage. Both holds the same value.
Similarly, for IBM MQ listener. When I look at attributes in the debugger I can see attributes.headers.messageId. Yet, when I capture it in munits using munit recording, the same value is captured in attributes.headers.JMSMessageID in JSON.
Which ones should I be using?

You should ask the IBM MQ connector question separately providing more details of the flow and the values at each point. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

In addition to what @Aled described.
These are very important exprssons in Mule error handling and both works differently.
The Mule error object is used to get information about errors in detail. The important expression in a mule error object are mainly these two -- error.errorMessage and error.description. These expressons are part of the public API and are guaranteed to be stable across all the Mule versions.
error.description: Provides a clear detailed description of the error occured.
error.errorMessage: it gives us additional details about the error if available.
It's important that when you debug your application in debugger mode, the debugger might show other expressions like muleMessage, but those are not officially documented. These internal attributes may change without any notice in future Mule releases, so that will cause your application to fail if it relies on them.
For JMS-related attributes, JMSMessageID is the standardized name according to JMS specifications and is likely the more reliable choice in your implementations.
Related official document- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/mule-error-concept#selector_expressions https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/mule-error-concept

I think you meant the opposite of The error.errorMessage provides a clear, concise description of the error, while the error.description offers additional details

yes @HarshankBansal I swapped it now

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

@DarkBee It is a general concept well-known to anyone familiar with MuleSoft error handling. There are also many YouTube videos and articles covering the same information. I Provided official documentation for reference.

My comment is rhetorical by the way, just looking at the grammar and style of your other answers (and the comment above) compared by this answer says enough

@DarkBee, i appreciate your concern but the answer is correct and I have provided all official info. now i have added one more official document for the same. do you want me to delete this answer?

Of course. Did you actually go through the linked article?

@DarkBee I am not able to delete the answer as its accepted. but i have Edited it. you can check

For errors you should only use the expressions that are documented: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/mule-error-concept#selector_expressions
In that documentation #[error.errorMessage] is documented but the other one not. Just because you see in the debugger some attributes does not mean you should use them. Some are used internally by Mule, but there are no guarantees they are going to be accessible in the future. Applications using those non documented values failed when they stopped being accessible because of internal changes in a Mule release.
